# Saving Custom TF Model returns TypeError: Unable to serialize 81 to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have been trying to save a custom peephole-LSTM neural network, which is returning an error.

I have defined Peephole layers with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class PeepholeLSTM(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False, **kwargs):
        super(PeepholeLSTM, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)
        self.return_sequences = return_sequences

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"units":self.units, "activation":self.activation, "return_sequences":self.return_sequences,
                       "Wf":self.Wf, "Wi":self.Wi, "Wc":self.Wc, "Wo":self.Wo,
                       "Uf":self.Uf, "Ui":self.Ui, "Uc":self.Uc, "Uo":self.Uo,
                       "bf":self.bf, "bi":self.bi, "bc":self.bc, "bo":self.bo,
                       "c_peephole":self.c_peephole, "o_peephole":self.o_peephole})
        return config

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]

        # Create weights for the LSTM cell
        self.Wf = self.add_weight(name='Wf', shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.Uf = self.add_weight(name='Uf', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer='orthogonal')
        self.bf = self.add_weight(name='bf', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')

        self.Wi = self.add_weight(name='Wi', shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.Ui = self.add_weight(name='Ui', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer='orthogonal')
        self.bi = self.add_weight(name='bi', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')

        self.Wc = self.add_weight(name='Wc', shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.Uc = self.add_weight(name='Uc', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer='orthogonal')
        self.bc = self.add_weight(name='bc', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')

        self.Wo = self.add_weight(name='Wo', shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.Uo = self.add_weight(name='Uo', shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer='orthogonal')
        self.bo = self.add_weight(name='bo', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')

        self.c_peephole = self.add_weight(name='c_peephole', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')
        self.o_peephole = self.add_weight(name='o_peephole', shape=(self.units,), initializer='zeros')

        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Initialize states
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        seq_length = tf.shape(inputs)[1]
        h_tm1 = tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, self.units))
        c_tm1 = tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, self.units))

        outputs = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=seq_length)

        for t in range(seq_length):
            x_t = inputs[:, t, :]
            f = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_t, self.Wf) + tf.matmul(h_tm1, self.Uf) + self.bf + self.c_peephole * c_tm1)
            i = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_t, self.Wi) + tf.matmul(h_tm1, self.Ui) + self.bi)
            c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(tf.matmul(x_t, self.Wc) + tf.matmul(h_tm1, self.Uc) + self.bc)
            o = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_t, self.Wo) + tf.matmul(h_tm1, self.Uo) + self.bo + self.o_peephole * c)
            h = o * self.activation(c)

            outputs = outputs.write(t, h)
            h_tm1 = h
            c_tm1 = c

        if self.return_sequences:
            return outputs.stack()
        else:
            return h
```

and have constructed the model like so:

```
NHN = 24
def LSTM(inpdata, oupdata, NHLayer=7, LR=LR0, DR=0.3, DS=3):
    inpshape = tf.shape(inpdata)[1:]
    oupshape = tf.shape(oupdata)[1:]
    Input = keras.Input(shape=inpshape)
    rnn = PeepholeLSTM(inpshape[1], activation=lambda x : capped_elu(x), return_sequences=True)(Input)
    for o in range(NHLayer):
        rnn = PeepholeLSTM(NHN, activation=lambda x : capped_elu(x), return_sequences=True)(rnn)
        if DR > 0 and o % DS == 0 and o != NHLayer - 1:
            rnn = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=DR)(rnn)
    Output = keras.layers.Dense(oupshape[1], activation=keras.activations.linear)(rnn)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=Input, outputs=Output)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(LR)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, weighted_metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

When I train and test this model, it works fine. However, when I run `model.save('model.h5')`, I get the following error callback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 247
--> 247 model.save('model.h5')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py:238, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder
    234 return cls(
    235     skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236     check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237     separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238     **kw).encode(obj)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py:200, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    196         return encode_basestring(o)
    197 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    198 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    199 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 200 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    201 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    202     chunks = list(chunks)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py:258, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    253 else:
    254     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    255         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    256         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    257         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 258 return _iterencode(o, 0)

TypeError: Unable to serialize 81 to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.
```

I cannot place the source of this error. 81 is the number of timesteps in the training dataset, so I figured I needed to convert the `batch_size` and `seq_length` variables in the peephole class to graph variables. This does not change anything.

Would greatly appreciate your insight into the source of this error.

TensorFlow Version 2.14.0.

Comment: You can solve it to  using the save_weights method:  
 
 

    model.save_weights('weights.h5')

To load you model use: 

 

    model.load_weights('weights.h5')